# JPA CriteriaBuilder FOR Filtering from Postgres Array

Tags: hibernate, jpa, postgresql-9.1, hibernate-criteria, jpa-2.1

Need help in creating filter Predicate for following query

```
SELECT * FROM table
    where
    'test_value' IN (SELECT unnest(data_array));
```

OR

```
Select *
FROM public.table
where 'test_value' = ANY (data_array);
```

JPA CriteriaBuilder FOR SELECTING from Postgres Array.

Table Format

```
id ,             
(char varying)

data_array
(text[])
```

I was trying to create filter for above query but finding it hard to get actual query filter working.

```
Expression function = builder.function("unnest", String.class, root.get(criteria.getKey()));
```

More info :-

Predicate has the code

```
class FilterSpecificaion implements Specification {
 public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {...} 
....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a work around with Postgres 9.5 we have more builtin functions. One of them is "array_positions" and I repurposed it to check if element is present. 
 https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-array.html

Comment: do you happen to have an example of how you managed to get this done, I am using an internal function which is an alias to containedBy operator but I just can't seem to get that to work, keep getting unknown function error as it passes the array as varchar

Comment: Did you get answer to your problem